# MODE in Teradata SQL - excluding a value from the range, and using multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, teradata, mode

I am comparing 3 tables of data for what should be the same demands, and want to create a table that shows the MODE from two of the tables (in order to make a suggestion of what the correct value could be). I may need to concatenate as I am looking for the mode of all rows with the same ID and Name.

Table 1:

```
+----------+----------+------+
| DemandNo | Forename | Size |
+----------+----------+------+
|        1 | Richard  |   42 |
|        2 | Richard  |   42 |
|        3 | Richard  |   42 |
|        4 | Richard  |   36 |
|        5 | Richard  |   36 |
|        6 | Richard  |   36 |
|        7 | Richard  |   36 |
|        8 | Luke     |   14 |
|        9 | Luke     |   14 |
|       10 | Luke     |   14 |
|       11 | Luke     |   14 |
|       12 | Luke     |   14 |
|       13 | Luke     |   25 |
|       14 | Luke     |   25 |
|       15 | Luke     |   25 |
+----------+----------+------+
```

Table 2:

```
+----------------+-----------------+
| List1_DemandNo | List1_PenColour |
+----------------+-----------------+
|              1 | White           |
|              2 | Black           |
|              3 | Black           |
|              4 | Red             |
|              5 | ?               |
|              6 | Red             |
|              7 | Red             |
|              8 | Yellow          |
|              9 | Yellow          |
|             10 | Yellow          |
|             11 | Green           |
|             12 | Yellow          |
|             13 | Green           |
|             14 | ?               |
|             15 | ?               |
+----------------+-----------------+
```

Table 3:

```
+----------------+-----------------+
| List2_DemandNo | List2_PenColour |
+----------------+-----------------+
|              1 | White           |
|              2 | Green           |
|              3 | Green           |
|              4 | Red             |
|              5 | ?               |
|              6 | Red             |
|              7 | Red             |
|              8 | Pink            |
|              9 | Pink            |
|             10 | Yellow          |
|             11 | Green           |
|             12 | Pink            |
|             13 | Orange          |
|             14 | Orange          |
|             15 | Orange          |
+----------------+-----------------+
```

So I need to generate a recommendation for each person with the same name and size. The recommendation should be the MODE of all rows in table1 where the person has the same Forename and Size (do I need to concatenate Forename and size?)

The other requirement is that all question marks "?" should be excluded from the MODE/recommendation.

So my results table should look something like this:

```
+----------+----------+-----+------------+------------+
| DemandNo | Forename | Size | List1_MODE | List2_MODE |
+----------+----------+-----+------------+------------+
|        1 | Richard  |  42 | Black      | Green      |
|        2 | Richard  |  42 | Black      | Green      |
|        3 | Richard  |  42 | Black      | Green      |
|        4 | Richard  |  36 | Red        | Red        |
|        5 | Richard  |  36 | Red        | Red        |
|        6 | Richard  |  36 | Red        | Red        |
|        7 | Richard  |  36 | Red        | Red        |
|        8 | Luke     |  14 | Yellow     | Pink       |
|        9 | Luke     |  14 | Yellow     | Pink       |
|       10 | Luke     |  14 | Yellow     | Pink       |
|       11 | Luke     |  14 | Yellow     | Pink       |
|       12 | Luke     |  14 | Yellow     | Pink       |
|       13 | Luke     |  25 | Green      | Orange     |
|       14 | Luke     |  25 | Green      | Orange     |
|       15 | Luke     |  25 | Green      | Orange     |
+----------+----------+-----+------------+------------+
```

I understand that the MODE function does not work in Teradata, and that I would need to perform a count, but the complexity of calculating the mode using 3 tables and excluding the ? is sadly beyond my SQL skills -Any help would be truly appreciated!

Many thanks
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a separate select for each mode and join to it:

```
select t1.*, List1_PenColour, List2_PenColour 
from table1 as t1
left join 
  (
    select Forename, Size, List1_PenColour
    from table1 as t1
    join table2 as t2
    on t1.DemandNo = t2.List1_DemandNo
    and List1_PenColour <> '?'
    group by Forename, Size, List1_PenColour
    -- return only the row with the highest count
    -- random row if multiple rows with the same count exist
    qualify row_number()
            over (partiton by Forename, Size, List1_PenColour 
                  order by count(*) desc) = 1 
  ) as list1
on t1.Forename = list1.Forename
and t1.Size = list1.Size
left join 
  (
    select Forename, Size, List2_PenColour
    from table1 as t1
    join table3 as t3
    on t1.DemandNo = t3.List2_DemandNo
    and List2_PenColour <> '?'
    group by Forename, Size, List2_PenColour
    qualify row_number() 
            over (partiton by Forename, Size, List2_PenColour 
                  order by count(*) desc) = 1 
  ) as list2
on t1.Forename = list2.Forename
and t1.Size = list2.Size
```

Comment: Thanks very much (once again!) for your help.... Do you normally charge for this? I feel like I owe you some money!

I have not fully checked the output from the above code yet but it seems to work, thank you!
(I did just change the List1_Pencolour to List2_PenColour in the bottom section (I think it was left the same as the top section from cut & paste?)

Comment: Unfortunately the code doesn't seem to give me what I need - It is returning some different results for some of the rows that share a common Forename and Size - I would have expected everything with the same Forename and Size to have the same MODE value for PenColour. This may be due to the random selection when there are more than one PenColour with same count... but this seems to happen on many of the rows, it is almost like it is counting duplicates but giving them a different PenColour, then giving both entries a random value

Comment: @Surfing: Unless there's another typo this should return the same color for each Forename/Size combination (at least the Derived Tables do that)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have probably made a mistake when editing the code to fit my real data. Really appreciate your help, cheers.

Comment: Is there a simple edit I can make to include columns for List1_PenColour, and List2_PenColour (to display the original values alongside the mode)?

Comment: @Surfing:  don't know what you mean, there's no more *original value* after an aggregation, `SELECT *` will return all you can get.